# Serialize custom field from an object in a list using the Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model that looks something like this:

```
class Foo:
    name = CharField()

class Bar:
    foo = ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='bars')
    bar_text = TextField()
```

I want the serialized version of Foo to look something like:

```
{
    bars : [
        "baz",
        "whizz"
    ]
}
```

i.e rather than displaying the `id`s of each bar, displaying the 'bar_text' field inside instead.

I think I'm aware of how to do this normally, i.e. if we had a single `bar` attribute under each 'Foo' rather than a list:

```
class FooSerializer(models.ModelSerializer):
    bar = serializers.TextField(source='bar.bar_text')
```

But I'm not sure how to perform the same override when using a 'bars' list, and don't seem to be able to find anything obvious!

EDIT: I forgot to mention - I think I can do this by overriding the `restore_object` function, but if there's a neater way, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a [`SlugRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) instead of a nested serializer.

```
class FooSerializer(models.ModelSerializer):
    bars = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='bar_text')
```

Comment: Thanks - this achieved what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

A solution that nearly works for me is to override the `bars` attribute on the `FooSerializer` with a `BarSerializer`:

```
class FooSerializer(models.ModelSerializer):
    bars = BarSerializer(many=True)
```

However, this gives me the following when serialized:

```
{
    bars: [
        {
            'bar_text' : 'baz',
        },
        { 
            'bar_text' : 'whizz'
        }
    ]
}
```

Which is fine, but I really want a list of `bar_text`s rather than key/value pairs. What's more, if I add more fields to `Bar` that I do not want to be serialized into `Foo`, I have no control over which are displayed here vs. a pure serialization of `Bar`. If I don't get a better solution I'll accept this shortly.